# Zend Framework 2 large page load time

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have installed the Skeleton application of ZF2 (from official GitHub repo), and the first page I see takes 400-700ms to load (default "Welcome to Zend Framework 2" page, with no database connections and without handling anything).

[image: Delay in page load]

In raw PHP (without frameworks) It'll take a few ms. to load.

Could You explain, what caused such a big delays?
I'm new to ZF, and now deciding, to use or not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework is a heavy php framework which uses a lot of php files. Because php is evaluted on the spot it takes a lot of time every request to evaluate these files. You should use a Opcode cache like apc and many others or if you're using php 5.5  Opcache that is built -in. An Opcode cache makes a copy of these evaluated files and stores these in memory. This gives a huge speed bonus.

Another thing that might be the problem is that if you run this ZF2 application with apache on windows it is much slower then apache on linux

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know whether this is good or bad without any info on the server you're running this test on. You also implied that this was a stock ZF2 skeleton app, but your screenshot shows what I think is the ZF2 developer toolbar, an add-on module.

I just tested a fresh checkout of the skeleton app on my (admittedly decent spec) dev machine and it loads in 30 ms (PHP 5.5). I would expect to be able to improve that with some simple production-type optimizations (classmap, config caching, superluminal etc.).

**Edit**: I thought I'd see what I could get this down to with some quick tweaks. I also installed the developer toolbar just to be sure this wasn't slowing things down too much. Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.4.17 on Apache (Windows Server 2008 x64 R2)
And yes, I forgot to tell about developer toolbar - I installed it after I mentioned that delay

Comment: Then if you don't have APC installed, either upgrading to PHP 5.5 or installing APC will give you a significant performance boost.

Comment: I understand, that caching will give performance boost. It seems to me a little odd that ZF2 designed for use with caching in any way.
If there will be very dynamic pages, caching will not help.

Comment: Opcaches (like APC and the one built into PHP 5.5) don't serve the same purpose as caches like memcache, I don't think you're clear on the difference. Opcaches benefit all PHP apps, but particularly those that use lots of PHP classes (like basically all frameworks). How dynamic the pages are is irrelevant, as opcaches cache PHP code, not your data.